# How to enforce authorization checks in every controller method?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I'm implementing [Resource-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in my web API.

I would like to force programmers to always call `_authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync` in every controller method.

**How do I ensure that a `403 Unauthorized` response is returned if some controller method completes without having at least once called `AuthorizeAsync`?**

I could also consider an attribute or some other way to explicitly mark a controller method as available without authorization. The main idea is to apply the principle "deny all, then allow some" and to prevent security holes just because somebody forgot to add an `AuthorizeAsync` call.

Comment: Why do you want to do auth inside your action methods? Just use `[Authorize]` (or your own derived version of it) and you can force that to be applied across your app.

Comment: If this is a general authorization requirement that applies to all routes, then you should adjust your default policy to take that requirement, so that it happens automatically when you use `[Authorize]`. Otherwise, you could always add a MVC authorization filter.

Comment: @DavidG I cannot use [Authorize] because it does not support the use cases I require (the quote from the Microsoft article: "If you're making decisions based on the outcomes of CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations"...). The resource-based authorization seems to be my best bet in this case to apply generic CRUD auth rules on any resource.

Answer (score 1):

Coding specific behaviours in your application to protect against coding practices is very strange.. Why don't you use static code analysis, something like SonarQube and create a custom rule to do this?

Comment: Good idea, thanks. The only drawback is that it's one more tool that every developer in the team has to become aware of and know how to configure and use properly.

Answer (score 0):

Invented a quick & dirty solution using Action Filter. I do the following inside HandleRequirementAsync:

```
    // add a flag to the context about the fact that authorization has been attempted
    // so that our custom ActionFilter can fail if programmer forgets to call authorization
    // on methods that are not explicitly marked with [AllowUnauthorized] attribute
    var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    httpContext.Items.Add(AuthAttemptedMark, true);
```

My Handler has also a helper function to determine if it has been called:

```
    public bool HasAuthorizationBeenAttemptedForRequest()
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        return httpContext.Items.ContainsKey(AuthAttemptedMark) &&
            (bool)httpContext.Items[AuthAttemptedMark];
    }
```

And then I have a filter:

public class RequestAuthorizationAttemptGuardFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        CrudResourceAuthorizationUserClaimHandler _authHandler;

```
    public RequestAuthorizationAttemptGuardFilter(CrudResourceAuthorizationUserClaimHandler authHandler)
    {
        _authHandler = authHandler;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    { }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // if the action did not have any authorization attempts
        // and was not marked as explicitly allowed,
        // then return forbidden
        if (!_authHandler.HasAuthorizationBeenAttemptedForRequest())
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
    }
}
```

Thus, the result gets replaced with `403 Forbidden`, if I detect that a programmer was lazy and forgot to add at least one call to authorization service.